# App crashes on some OS (Swing with AWT)

Tags: java, swing, jenkins, noclassdeffounderror, windowbuilder

I have written an application in JAVA with a GUI using Window Builder with Eclipse. More specifically, the application is a questionnaire, where the questions are retrieved from a database and the answers are also stored there.

I have used the standard SWING components found in Window Builder, but for handling events and for changing color/fonts I have used AWT.

The problem is that, although the app runs OK on most systems (on my windows 7 has never crashed), it crashes - throws the following unexpectedly on some other systems:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:....
```

This is happening usually on linux and MAINLY if the executable .jar file is built by JENKINS.

After searching for this on the Internet for a while, I read that it is no good mixing SWING adn AWT, but after trying to remove all AWT packages from my code, I just could not manipulate some simple thins (font colors and dimensions) without having a AWT imported.

I am posting below the list of imports in my code

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
```

Can such an exception be thrown due to some failing of SWING working with AWT? And if so is there a way so that I can manipulate everything with SWING?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT the exception thrown is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wBPGui/Demographics/CurrentSkill$17
    at wBPGui.Demographics.CurrentSkill.<init>(CurrentSkill.java:414)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2820)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.processKeyEvent(JComboBox.java:1417)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: What class is actually missing? It's more likely that a 3rd party jar which is not been distributed

Comment: Sorry about half-posting the exception. The missing part is the referred to be the next class file. The exception is thrown after a "next" button is pressed, which triggers openning a new window (next window). This window is actually openned and created by a java class file and that is what the exception tell it's missin. But this only happens if the jar file is built by Jenkins. If built manually on eclipse there is no problem.

Comment: I'd unzip the jar file and outlet check its contents

Comment: Swing and Java are not acronyms

Comment: @MadProgrammer. I unzipped the jar file and compared it to another working version of the app. It had one file less. When I added the missing file and zipped everything together, the jar worked ok. It seems that something goes wrong with the Jenkins autobuilt. Anyway thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

AWT IS a part of Swing... some classes are shared, and Swing toolkit is in fact just built on AWT ones. The bad idea is to mix AWT and Swing elements - for example, having an awt.Label in a swing.JPanel.

The exception you are getting is most likely some incompatibility between platforms. For example, if you use Windows look and feel on Linux, then it's just not gonna work, as the Windows LaF uses some elements available only on Windows.

I would recommend cutting away all non-important fancy stuff and stick with default Java settings for everything. If that's not gonna work, then you need to debug the Exception in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have not used any LaF features on the app. I will however try to remove any extra graphic style (background pictures etc) and try again! One more...do you think that auto-built via Jenkins has to do with this problem at all? Because I ran a jar of the same app buit from Jenkins and I got (on windows) the same expcetion

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @Dimitris AWT is skeleton, all lightweight Swing methods are based, implements, inherits from AWT Compnents are always on top, then they can to cover, overlay lightweight Swing JComponents